# SQL count date time

Tags: sql, count, concatenation

I have to concatenate the date and time portion of two fields, which I have managed to do, then  I need to test if the result is < `getdate()`

```
select count(cast(cast(DischargeDatenew as date) as datetime) + cast(DischargeTime as time))as Requiredby FROM [dbo].[Main]
 where Location = 'Home' and ScriptTypeID = '1' and Requiredby < GETDATE()
```

Unfortunately the second `Requiredby` comes up as an invalid column name. How can I get this query to work? Do I need a subquery?

Comment: could you elaborate the question giving some details of the table on which this query is being executed?

Comment: What's the actual datatypes of DischargeDatenew and DischargeTime? And what's your DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will need subquery:

```
select * from (select someExpression as Requiredby 
               FROM [dbo].[Main] 
               where Location = 'Home' and ScriptTypeID = '1') t 
where Requiredby < GETDATE()
```

But I really think you want this:

```
select sum(case when cast(cast(DischargeDatenew as date) as datetime) +
                     cast(DischargeTime as time) < getdate() then 1 
                     else 0 end) as Requiredby 
FROM [dbo].[Main] 
where Location = 'Home' and ScriptTypeID = '1'
```

Comment: Just to add some background information: The where clause runs before the select caluse, this is the reason you can't use aliases from the select caluse on the where caluse.

Comment: @JediPhantom1, dnoeth user has a better variation on my second answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the calculation in COUNT, simply move it to WHERE:

```
select count(*) 
FROM [dbo].[Main]
where Location = 'Home' and ScriptTypeID = '1'
and cast(cast(DischargeDatenew as date) as datetime)
       + cast(DischargeTime as time) < GETDATE()
```